# Cent OS VM not resolving DNS via nslookup ?! all zones/conf OK

Tags: centos, dns, vmware

I have virtual setup on NAT in VMWare with a Cent OS as a DNS Server (192.168.102.159), I ran the zone and conf test through bind named, allresults are OK, when I run nslookup from a client I get :

```
nslookup
> server 192.168.102.159
Default server: 192.168.102.159
Address: 192.168.102.159#53
```

For the reverse lookup I get :

```
nslookup ns1.abc.local
Server:     192.168.102.2
Address:    192.168.102.2#53
** server can't find ns1.abc.local: NXDOMAIN
```

CONFIG FILES
ifcfg-ens33

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens33
UUID=c39a3132-fecb-4688-aa6a-b83e4d8f09a3
DEVICE=ens33
HOSTNAME=ns2
IPADDR=192.168.102.159
SUBNETMASK=255.255.255.0
ADAPTER=ens33
GATEWAY=192.168.102.2
DNS1="192.168.102.2
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
```

named.conf

```
acl internals { 192.168.102.0/24;  };
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.102.159; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { localhost; internals; };

        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "abc.local" { type master; file "abc.db"; };

zone "102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" { type master; file "cba.db"; };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

abc.db

```
$TTL 3H
$ORIGIN abc.local.

@       IN SOA ns1.abc.local. admin.abc.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.abc.local.

ns1     IN A 192.168.102.159
```

cba.db

```
$TTL 3H
$ORIGIN 102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.

@       IN SOA ns1.abc.local. admin.abc.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.abc.local.

100     IN PTR ns1.abc.local.
```

Zone and Conf check reports

```
[root@localhost ~]# named-checkzone 102.168.192.in-addr.arpa /var/named/cba.db
zone 102.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
OK
[root@localhost ~]# named-checkzone abc.local /var/named/abc.db
zone abc.local/IN: loaded serial 0
OK
[root@localhost ~]# named-checkconf
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Firewall is configured as :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It seems you are querying `192.168.102.2` instead of `192.168.102.159`. Does `nslookup ns1.abc.local 192.168.102.159` work? If yes, reconfigure `DNS1="192.168.102.159` and you might want to configure a `forwarders` section including `192.168.102.2`.

Comment: Changed that DNS IP to 192.168.102.159, the client nslookup still results in the same answer, is this the IP I have to add to the client as well ? Currently the client usesthe DHCP and DNS of VMWare..

Comment: Well, you have to configure your clients to use the DNS server at a specific IP address. If they get the DNS from DHCP, then you have to configure the DHCP server which IP address to hand out for DHCP clients.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr Thomas, the issue is resolved, apparently, I was so into it that I even forgot I was using a machine that is not configured properly to check the DNS, even though the client was in the NAT network it was not issued a DHCP by the Cent OS Server and thus it did not have any DNS configuration either, I was testing the client by manually adding entries. Finally I tested it through putty as before and both forward and reverse lookups are resolving successfully. Thank you all for your guidance and time, appreciate it.